# How does the function cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatchImpl() work?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a computer vision course with OpenCV (C++) at my university, and I have a task to implement keypoints descriptor matcher by overriding functions cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatchImpl() and cv::DescriptorMatcher::knnMatchImpl().

So I get a target image (snapshot from web-camera) and then my program must to match this image descriptors with descriptors of frames from the web-camera stream. But I don't understand what is argument of the function cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatchImpl() that corresponds to the target image?

I have found its documentation and its desciption is:

`virtual void radiusMatchImpl (InputArray queryDescriptors, std::vector< std::vector< DMatch > > &matches, float maxDistance, InputArrayOfArrays masks=noArray(), bool compactResult=false) CV_OVERRIDE`

If I understand correctly, `queryDescriptors` is cv::Mat that coressponds to the frame descriptors from the videostream. But where is the argument corresponding to the image descriptors with which we should compare this frame?

Comment: Like it name suggests it is private virtual function called by function radiusMatch probably documented at same place. As I understand the stuff you use is supposed to be trained and the training data is provided during that training not each time you start to match based on said training.

Comment: Do you mean, that I must to override the function cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatchImpl, but there function cv::DescriptorMatcher::radiusMatch is being called in the code?

Comment: You yourselfs seemingly said that you have to derive your own descriptormatcher(s)? These should likely work by some other, your custom algorithms, that you avoided describing in the question. These algorithms are presumably something else than for example algorithm of bfmatcher or flannbasedmatcher. But you have to implement your algorithm using same interfaces as said descriptormatchers do.

Comment: the "missing" argument is because the `DescriptorMatcher` would have been *trained* before, i.e. given a "data base" of descriptors (look for the `train` method). the two query types should implement a query on this data base. "knn" asks for the k entries nearest to the query in the data base, "radius" asks for all entries that are within the given distance to the query point.